# Add options to dropdown with ajax

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I am trying to use ajax in my form to dynamically add options to the dropdown, with the click of a button. The value entered in the textbox must be added to the dropdown. However i am not sure how to retain the added values in the dropdown.
Currently only the recently added value remains in the dropdown.

This is my module code:

```
<?php
function dropdown_menu(){
    $items['dropdown_form'] = array(
        'title' => 'Dynamic Dropdown',
        'description' => 'adding more textfields',
         'access callback' => 'dropdown_access',
         'access arguments' => array(1),
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form', //used during form api
        'page arguments' => array('dropdown'),
    );
    return $items;
} 

function dropdown_access() {
    return TRUE;
} 

function dropdown($form, &$form_state, $no_js_use = FALSE) {
   $form['field_name'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Field Name:  String, Woodwind, Brass, Percussion'),
      '#required' => TRUE, 
    );    

   $field_val = isset($form_state['values']['field_name']) ? $form_state['values']['field_name'] : '';

  $form['add_to_dropdown'] = array(
      '#type' => 'button',
      '#value' => 'Add To Dropdown',      
     '#ajax' => array(      
      'event' => 'click',
      'callback' => 'dropdown_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'dropdown-second-replace',
    ),
    );  

  $form['dropdown_second'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => 'Dynamic Dropdown',    
    '#prefix' => '<div id="dropdown-second-replace">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',    
    '#options' => get_dropdown_options($field_val),
    '#default_value' => isset($form_state['values']['dropdown_second']) ? $form_state['values']['dropdown_second'] : '',
  );  

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit'),
    '#prefix' => '<br><br><div id="submit_btn">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    );
    return $form;
}

function dropdown_callback($form, $form_state) {        
    return $form['dropdown_second'];
}

function get_dropdown_options($key = '') {
  $options = array(
    t($key) => drupal_map_assoc(array(t($key))),    
  );
  if (isset($options[$key])) {
    return $options[$key];
  }
  else {
    return array();
  }
}

function dropdown_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  print_r($form_state['values']); exit();  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should merge the existing vales in `$form['dropdown_second']['#options']` with the one in `$form_state['values']['field_name']`

something like this:

```
$existing_options = isset($form['dropdown_second']['#options']) ? $form['dropdown_second']['#options'] : array();
$new_option = get_dropdown_options($field_val);

$form['dropdown_second'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => 'Dynamic Dropdown',    
    '#prefix' => '<div id="dropdown-second-replace">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',    
    '#options' => array_merge($existing_options, $new_option),
    '#default_value' => isset($form_state['values']['dropdown_second']) ? $form_state['values']['dropdown_second'] : '',
  );
```

Comment: I used: **$form['dropdown_second']['#options'][] = $form_state['values']['field_name'];** inside my **dropdown_callback** function, but now it is adding the same value twice.

Comment: try and use it inside the `dropdown` function. I updated the answer with an example.

Comment: Still unable to add the options to the dropdown. Only the lastly added option exists in the dropdown.

Comment: Finally i had to adopt a jquery ajax solution for achieving my need. I used something like: **'#attributes' => array('onClick' => 'add_to_dropdown("field-name"); return false;'),** for the button and then used jquery ajax for catching the input field value and adding it as an option in the dropdown. Still hoping to do it with drupal ajax.